# Make the statement true!

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle

You need to add a single line and make the statement true

> $5+5=5$

All the numbers are made by matchsticks.

Comment: are you sure it's *add a line* and not *move a match*? I know a variant on this where the answer is `IV + I = V` - you move one of the two matches forming the second V to create IV and leave I behind.

Comment: no its add a match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trivial Answer. 
If they are made by matchsticks, then:

> Add a single matchstick obliquely on equal sign to make it non-equality sign. After all 5 + 5 is not equal to 5
>  $$5+5\ne5$$

Comment: good you did it try out my other puzzle

Comment: I would try now. If it is correct answer, please mark answer as accepted. :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution:

> $$5+5⩾5$$

Excuse the fact that there's a rotation issue - the markup for equations doesn't appear to permit rotations to fix it.